# Can I assign an image gradient to a rectangle

Tags: java, image, graphics

I'm currently making Mario as a school graphics project.

I have most of the collisions done, but I just want the land and bricks to actually look like land and bricks instead of just colored rectangles. I have an ImageIcon for the "land" in my graphics project. The problem is that it is only 16x16 pixels large. In order to make enough land by just making each part of the land one 16x16 pixel, it would essentially be horribly inefficient.

I was wondering if I could get the ImageIcon or possibly buffered image and use it as the "color" for a rectangle to make the chunks of land easier. If that's not possible, can you offer other suggestions on how to go about this problem?

Comment: What underlying GUI? Swing, JavaFX, HTML? One can use _textures_ as repeated background tiles, where the right of an image fits to the left of the same image and such. Swing/AWT [Graphics2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) with miscellaneous [Paint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Paint.html) is one pointer.

Comment: @JoopEggen Swing GUI. And that sounds like exactly what I need. How would I be able to implement an image as a texture for the background tile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a background of tiled images, a texture:

```
private BufferedImage image;

    URL url = getClass().getResource("/mytexture.png");
    assert url != null;
    image =  ImageIO.read(url);

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    Rectangle textureRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
    TexturePaint paint = new TexturePaint(image, textureRect);
    g2.setPaint(paint);
    g2.fill(rect);        
}
```

In general create your own JPanel.

Gimp and other tools allow to create a tilable image by ensuring that a line running to a border will enter at the opposite border.